# Figma: increasing Frame size also increases size of icons on that frame?

Tags: vector, icon, figma

I'm using Font Awesome vector icons in my designs. When I go to increase/transform the size of a frame the size of the icons also transform with it, but all other elements on the frame remain the same size.

Is there a solution to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably happening because the **icon constraints are set to Scale** OR **Left and Right and Top and Bottom**. This is making the icon stretch with the frame size.

[image]
[image]

If the constraints are set to any 2 sides of the frame such as Top and Left, it will solve your problem.
How to do this: Click on the icon placed on the frame > update the constraints

[image]